# How I get the state of the like in Facebook graph API v2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the object_id in the following procedure.

/v2.2/me/home?fields=id,attachments

object_id is returns ["id"] Or ["attachments"] ["data"] [0] ["target"] ["id"]

I am getting the like_count with the following request.

/v2.2/{object_id}/likes?summary=true

like_count is the total_count found in the summary.

And, I want to know whether the user is already the like.
Because, when I request the like, I do not know what should I use which post or delete.

I can do with FQL.
Please tell me how I get the state of the like without using FQL?
Is there an elegant way than how to find a name by request limit=200?

Comment: may i ask why you would want to know if the authorized user liked a specific post on his own timeline?

Comment: "specific post" the user's friends posted.
I request a "/v2.2/me/home", to obtain the post.

Users want to "like" the post of friends.

I might get a state of "like" in "/v2.2/me/home".
But, I want to do without waste this.

I know the only post_id.
And I get the total_count from post_id.
Users want to "like" the post of friends.
(The posting user's friends have posted)
Before that,
- Whether the user is "like" for the post -
I want to show it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "specific post" the user's friends posted

That´s the main part of your question. It is not possible to get posts of user friends. You would need the read_stream permission to get friend posts in the user stream. But you will never get read_stream approved by Facebook. See this link for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

...which means, you will not be able to get likes on those posts, of course.

Comment: I'm sorry.
Because I am a Japanese, whether my understanding is correct, I want to check it again.
Are you saying does not include posting of the user's friends in the /v2.2/me/home?
I use the id of posts obtained by /v2.2/me/home,
I can get the total_count when I request the /v2.2/{id}/likes?summary=true.
But, in the post of the user's friends, whether the user is like to it, I can not get. Mean that?
Is it also a Facebook page same?

Comment: i mean, you would need to get read_stream approved by facebook, but facebook will not approve that permission. see the reference link. facebook pages are a completely different topic.

Comment: I will not get the post of the user's friends without permission of read_stream?
I can get the post of the user's friends with / me / home now, but it will not be included them?
The reason I can get it now, version of the API is involved?

That I do not know in particular, is "but facebook will not approve that permission". I read the reference link. If I submit a review, I think is allowed. Is my understand wrong? Why "will not approve" What?

I'm sorry for writing a full "?".

Comment: /me/home needs read_stream. you can submit it, but it will not get approved. please just check out the link i posted, it´s in there.

Comment: Oh. Now I finally know. I had the understanding that okay not need to do anything. To do so, I'm sorry to not proceed story. I have understood by now. And, I was glad I noticed now. It also thanks luschn that did the talking. I have to clarify the problem, will post a new topic. Thank you.